# Scala EitherT Future Exception handling

Tags: scala, scala-cats

In the below method, only the exception coming from   burnService.execute is getting caught in the catch. Any exception coming from earnService.execute is not getting caught. If I move the earnService,execute to top of the for comprehension, the error from earnService is caught but not from burnService.

```
private def processSearchItems(
      processedValuesCtx: OffersProcessedValuesCtx
  ): Future[Either[APIError, Seq[OfferV3Response]]] = {
    implicit val baseInfo: BaseInfo = BaseInfo.apply(this)

    val searchResults = processedValuesCtx.req.requestWrapperInternal.offers.searchResults
    // Process the search results
    val result        = searchResults.map { searchResult =>
      try {
        val searchItem                = enrichSearchItemWithPricingTokenData(searchResult)
        val searchItemProcessedValues = buildProcessedValues(searchItem, processedValuesCtx)

        (for {

          burnResponse                    <- EitherT(
                                               burnService.execute(
                                                 processedValuesCtx,
                                                 searchItemProcessedValues
                                               )
                                             )
          enrichedProcessedValuesAfterBurn =
            updateItemProcessedValuesAfterBurn(processedValuesCtx, burnResponse, searchItemProcessedValues)
          earnResponse                    <- EitherT(
                                               earnService.execute(
                                                 processedValuesCtx,
                                                 enrichedProcessedValuesAfterBurn
                                               )
                                             )

          splitTenders                    <- EitherT(
                                               splitTenderResponseTransformer
                                                 .buildSplitTenderResponse(
                                                   burnResponse,
                                                   earnResponse,
                                                   processedValuesCtx,
                                                   searchItemProcessedValues
                                                 )
                                             )
        } yield {
          val finalTenders = splitTenderResponseTransformer
            .removeChargeSplitsTooCloseApart(splitTenders, processedValuesCtx)
            .sortBy(_.burn.map(_.points))

          OfferV3Response(
            offerIdentifier = searchResult.identifier,
            priceInfo = PriceInfoV3ResponseWrapper(splitTenders = finalTenders),
            priceUsedToCalculate = getPriceUsedToCalculate(processedValuesCtx)
          )
        }).value

      } catch {
        case ex: Exception =>
          // log and build empty response
          logger.logError(
            rc.toBaseLog(
              s"Exception occurred!! while calculating offer :: ${ex.getMessage}",
              Some(ex)
            )
          )
               Future.successful(Right(resp))
      }
    }
    EitherUtils.sequenceOfFutureEither(result)
  }
```

Tried few things seems like none of the approaches worked

Comment: Follow-up: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77284043/scala-cats-exception-handling

Answer (score 2):

That's the expected behaviour: `eitherT1.flatMap(eitherT2)` will not "accumulate" errors, if the 1st fails you'll only get the 1st error.

It's the same as you'd get with a regular `Future` or `Either`.

If you want to accumulate errors, with Cats you can look at [`Validated`](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html).