# Scala cats exception handling

Tags: scala, scala-cats

Why does it not catch and print the exception msg from calculateTwo? If we make calculateOne throw the exception, the exception is caught and the msg is printed.

```
  package com.oxo.test
    
    import cats.data.EitherT
    import cats.implicits._
    
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    import scala.concurrent.Future
    
    object FutureError extends App {
    
      try {
        (for {
          result      <- EitherT(calculateOne())
          resultTwo   <- EitherT(calculateTwo())
          resultThree <- EitherT(calculateThree())
          sum          = result + resultTwo + resultThree
        } yield {
          sum
        })
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => println(e.getMessage)
      }
    
      private def calculateOne(): Future[Either[String, Int]] = {
        //throw new RuntimeException("error from one")
        Future.successful(Right(1))
      }
    
      private def calculateTwo(): Future[Either[String, Int]] = {
        //throw new RuntimeException("error from two")
        //Future.successful(Right(2))
      }
    
      private def calculateThree(): Future[Either[String, Int]] = {
        //throw new RuntimeException("error from three")
        Future.successful(Right(3))
      }
    
    }
```

**========= UPDATE =================**

From the responses I understand that any exception from first future get thrown right away and any errors from subsequent Futures results in Future.failed. Since we don't want to mix and match with try catch,
Is there any elegant way for the below code to continue processing the loop? Irrespective of from where the exception is thrown, handle the error and move on to next element.

```
 package com.oxo.test
    
    import cats.data.EitherT
    import cats.implicits._
    
    import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    import scala.concurrent.Future
    
    object FutureError extends App {
    
      val processingList = List(1, 2, 3)
    
      processingList.map { x =>
        val k = (for {
          result      <- EitherT(calculateOne(x))
          resultTwo   <- EitherT(calculateTwo(x))
          resultThree <- EitherT(calculateThree(x))
          sum          = result + resultTwo + resultThree
        } yield {
          sum
        }).value
    
        k.map {
          case Right(value) =>
            println("This gets printed" + value);
          case Left(value)  =>
            println("This error gets printed" + value);
        }.recover {
          case _ =>
            println("processing value" + x);
            println("This error gets printed");
        }
      }
    
      private def calculateOne(input: Int): Future[Either[String, Int]] = {
        throw new RuntimeException("error from one")
        //Future.successful(Right(input + 1))
      }
    
      private def calculateTwo(input: Int): Future[Either[String, Int]] = {
        //throw new RuntimeException("error from two")
        Future.successful(Right(input + 2))
      }
    
      private def calculateThree(input: Int): Future[Either[String, Int]] = {
        //throw new RuntimeException("error from three")
        Future.successful(Right(input + 3))
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: That code is mixing direct style with `throw + catch`, pseudo monadic with `Future`, and real monadic with `Either`. This is a recipe for disaster, extremely high metal load, and ditching the language because _"it requires a PhD"_. - Anyways, the reason why it is not caught on `calculateTwo`, is because the `flatMap` method in `Future` catches exceptions.

Comment: Since you have independent computations you could use `Applicative` composition to run all operations concurrently and then accumulate the errors. However, `Future` being a faulty `Monad` does not play nice with **cats** constructs, and its combination is discouraged.

Comment: A simpler option is to lift all failures inside the `Either` context, use normal monadic _(`for`)_ composition for the `Futures`, and then use `parMapN` on the `Eithers` to merge the errors.

Answer (score 2):

As it's been said by others: mixing `throw/try..catch` with `Future/Either/EitherT` is asking for trouble. Stick to one model or the other.

---

Now, let's understand what's happening in your code.

Your example can be simplified to the following code which behaves in the same way:

```scala
calculateOne()
  .flatMap(_ => calculateTwo())
```

`calculateTwo()` will "execute inside" a `Future`, any exception will be swallowed by the `Future` and result in a `Future.failed`. It's roughly the same as if you had written:

```scala
calculateOne.flatMap { _ =>
  Future { 
    throw new Exception(...)
  }
}
```

Which itself is roughly the same as:

```scala
calculateOne.flatMap { _ =>
  Future.failed(new Exception(...)) // no throw!
}
```

The overall expression results in no exception but a `Future.failed`.

---

Now, if `calculateOne()` throws an exception, it's not yet "in" a `Future` and is roughly the same as:

```scala
throw new Exception(...)
calculateTwo() // not even called, dead code
```

Which is just throwing an exception.

It is NOT the same as:

```scala
Future.failed(new Exception())
  .flatMap(_ => calculateTwo())
```

Which would result in no exception but a failed `Future`.

Answer (score 0):

`EitherT` and `try ... catch` are two completely orthogonal exception handling mechanisms. To deal with result-type-style exceptions like `EitherT`, we simply call methods on the class, rather than using a special control construct. For instance, [`getOrElse`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.typelevel/cats-docs_2.13/2.10.0/cats/data/EitherT.html#getOrElse%5BBB%3E:B%5D(default:=%3EBB)(implicitF:cats.Functor%5BF%5D):F%5BBB%5D) is a good choice in your situation.

```
(for {
  result      <- EitherT(calculateOne())
  resultTwo   <- EitherT(calculateTwo())
  resultThree <- EitherT(calculateThree())
  sum          = result + resultTwo + resultThree
} yield {
  sum
}).getOrElse(whateverDefaultValue)
```

Keep in mind that handling the exception does not excuse you from returning a value of the appropriate type. If `sum` is an `Int`, then the result of handling error conditions *also* needs to be an `Int`. If you're not returning an `Int` in that case, you're not handling the exception; you're propagating it.